# Why does pandas.to_parquet need so much RAM?

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow, fastparquet

Wisdom of such a use case aside... how come a machine with 512Gb RAM (and nothing else running) run out of memory while trying to save a pandas df (`df.to_parquet(...)`) that has object size (`sys.getsizeof`) "only" ~25Gb? The df is ~73mm rows by 2 columns, one of them is one English natural-language sentence, the other string id.

With `engine='fastparquet'`, it just quits with an error about overflow; with default `pyarrow` it runs out of memory. In both cases, `compresssion` setting (default, `gzip` or `None`) does not change that respective behavior. Same result 3 times.

Comment: `sys.getsizeof` may not give you the full picture. You should try `df.memory_usage(deep=True)`. Compression will not help the memory usage (it will only reduce the disk space of the parquet file).

Comment: What happens if you assign the DF to a PA table?  ie `table=pa.Table.from_pandas(DF)`  Does that work?